# How to add random point size to this distribution of 3d points?

Tags: graphics3d, random, generative-art, version-7, size

The code below creates a random distribution of points in 3D.  Currently, the points have a random size, and the size is the same for all points.  I need the points to get individually a random size, not the same for all points.  How can I modify that code to do that?  Please, the solution should work with old versions of Mathematica (I'm still using version 7.0 since my computer is very old).  The colors could be random too, but I want to concentrate on the size first.

```
points3D[p_, q_, r_] := Module[{dat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {p, 3}]},
Do[AppendTo[dat, r RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3] + RandomChoice[dat]], {i, q}]; dat
]

graph3D[p_, q_, r_] := Graphics3D[{RGBColor[{0.5, 0.4, 1.0, 0.4}], PointSize[RandomReal[{0.004, 0.01}]], Point[points3D[p, q, r]]}]

view[p_, q_, r_] := Show[{graph3D[p, q, r]},
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    Boxed -> True,
    Background -> Black,
    ImageSize -> {700, 700},
    SphericalRegion -> True,
    Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}
]

view[200, 5000, 0.1]
```

Preview of what this code is doing:

[image]

As you can notice on this picture, the points are all having the same size.  I need them to get different random sizes.

Comment: Each `Point` must have its own `PointSize`. Change definition of `graph3D` to `graph3D[p_, q_, r_] := Graphics3D[{RGBColor[{0.5, 0.4, 1.0, 0.4}], {PointSize[RandomReal[{0.004, 0.01}]], Point[#]} & /@ points3D[p, q, r]}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon, I'm getting a problem with your solution.  As is, it's working great.  But as soon as I put it in a manipulate box to play with the variables (p, q, r), Mathematica aborts the compilation after some delay.  There's something fishy.  Is there another way in writing your suggestion, without the &/@ (which appears to give troubles to my old version of Mma)

Comment: Turn off synchronous updating, i.e., `Manipulate[view[p, q, r],
 {{p, 200}, 100, 300, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{q, 5000}, 2000, 8000, 1000, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{r, 0.1}, 0.05, 0.2, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> All,
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]`

Comment: `{PointSize[RandomReal[{0.004, 0.01}]], Point[#]} & /@ points3D[p, q, r]` is the same as `Map[{PointSize[RandomReal[{0.004,0.01}]], Point[#]}&, points3D[p,q,r]]`

Comment: I tried your last suggestion.  It works outside the manipulate box.  But when I use the function view[p, q, r] in a manipulate box, I still have an $Aborted output.

Comment: @BobHanlon. Hmmm, now the manipulate box works (with the SynchronousUpdating -> False), but it's extremely slow!

Comment: @BobHanlon, what about modifying the **points3D[p, q, r]** function to add a fourth coordinate that would define the size?  But then, how to modify **Point[points3D[p, q, r]]** so only the first three coordinates are used to place the points?

Comment: `AppendTo` is inefficient, use `Table` and `Join`, i.e., `points3D[p_, q_, r_] := Module[{dat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {p, 3}]}, Join[dat, Table[r RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3] + RandomChoice[dat], {i, q}]]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon, WOW!  It improves the speed enormously!  Thanks!!

Comment: @BobHanlon, eeww!  The new code now produces cubic distributions when **p** is low.  It destroys the natural looking distribution.  There's someting wrong in that code.

Comment: I have no idea what code you are using. I recommend that you post a new question showing the full code that you are using and explain what problems you are having and what you expect in the end result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getPts[n_, noise_] := 
 Module[{dat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 3}]}, 
  Do[AppendTo[dat, noise RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3] + RandomChoice[dat]], 
   n]; {PointSize[RandomReal[{0.003, 0.006}]], Point[#]} & /@ dat] 

Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[getPts[n, noise], 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {{noise, 0.1}, 0, 
  0.4}, {{n, 1000}, 100, 5000}]
```

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion gives me the same trouble as Bob:  the &/@ appears to stop the compilation (while I checked all the code).  Mma just $Abort the compilation, I don't know why.

Comment: I have MMA version 13.1 Maybe we have a version problem. Try e.g. `getPts[100,1]` and see if you get some reasonable output like: {{PointSize[0.00524523], Point[{0.153324, -0.916432, 0.910523}]},....``

Comment: The compilation of your code (without modifications) is extremely slow on my system.  Yes I get something like in your previous comment...

Comment: To get 1000 points it takes 0.015 sec on a not too new PC.

Comment: It now works (using Bob suggestion of SynchronousUpdating -> False) but it's extremely slow!  There's surely another way of adding random Sizes.  Maybe at the level of dat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {p, 3}]

Comment: Daniel, instead of using **Point[#]} & /@ points3D[p, q, r]**, is there a way to define a new function: **size[p, q, r]**, that depends on each point in **points3D[p, q, r]**, and use it as **PointSize[size[p, q, r], Point[points3D[p, q, r]]**?

Comment: You have to specify a new  point size for every point and this is what  `{PointSize[RandomReal[{0.003, 0.006}]], Point[#]} & /@ dat` does

Answer (score 0):

You might get better performance if you avoid the Module and Do loop:

```
points3D[locusCount_, cloudPointCount_, cloudRadius_] :=
  With[
    {locii = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {locusCount, 3}]},
    randomCloudPoint[cloudRadius] /@ RandomChoice[locii, cloudPointCount]]
```

We determine the cloud "centers" or "locii" and then generate a random sample of them which we will then map our "fuzzing" function over. I introduced a function `randomCloudPoint` for this:

```
randomCloudPoint[radius_][locus_] := locus + RandomReal[{-radius, radius}, 3]
```

This gives a uniform distribution. You could use different distributions (not sure what's available in your version):

```
randomCloudPoint[radius_][locus_] := 
  locus + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, radius/3], 3]
```

I used SubValues to make the mapping part simpler.

Now, as has previously been mentioned/demonstrated, you need to come up with a style for each point. I put this into another function:

```
randomPointStyle[ptSizeRange_, baseColor_, colorRange_][pt_] := 
  {PointSize[RandomReal[ptSizeRange]], 
   Darker[baseColor, RandomReal[{-colorRange, colorRange}]],
   Point[pt]}
```

There would be other ways to randomize the color.

The new `graph3D` looks like this:

```
graph3D[p_, q_, r_] := 
  Graphics3D[randomPointStyle[{.001, .01}, RGBColor[{0.5, 0.4, 1.0, 0.8}], .5] /@ points3D[p, q, r]]
```

(Didn't rename the arguments this time.)
I changed the opacity a bit so the color variation was more obvious.

Here's a Manipulate:

```
Manipulate[
  view[locusCount, totalCount, cloudRadius], 
  {{locusCount, 20}, 1, 200, 1}, 
  {{totalCount, 500}, 1, 5000, 1}, 
  {{cloudRadius, .1}, .01, .5}]
```

(I didn't change view, but it would depend on the new functions above.)

Comment: I'm still having $Aborted issue.  Without a random Size, my code was working great.  Adding the random size gives the same issue.